# Python dict-like device for key-value pairs that allows enums as keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, static

I have 2 classes which inherit from enum, let's call them Class1 and Class2, i.e.

```
class Class1(Enum):
    ItemA = 'ItemA'
    ItemB = 'ItemB'
    ItemC = 'ItemC'
```

For each item in Class1 I would like to have a dictionary with keys from Class2 and values from Class1. Basically I need something like this, a static object that I can access throughout my application:

```
d = {Class1.ItemA: {Class2.ItemX: Class1.ItemB, Class2.ItemY: Class1.ItemC},
Class1.ItemB: {Class2.ItemX: Class1.ItemD, Class2.ItemY: Class1.ItemE}}
```

How could I achieve this so that I can still make use of the built-in magic of dictionaries such as:

```
if Class1.ItemA in d
```

Any feedback appreciated :)

Comment: Can you please describe what is your problem? `Class1.ItemA in d` correctly returns `True` for me.

Comment: Is there a reason you could not override `__contains__` in a class to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

By creating custom class dictionary:

```py
class Class1KeyDictionary():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # Expect iterable of (key, value) pairs
        self.dictionary = {key.value: value for key, value in args}
    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key.value in self.dictionary
```

Python classes should have unique id used in dictionary lookups which would mean that such override is not necessary in most cases.